# Adding class to dynamically appended elements with jQuery function in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, addclass

Have tried a few options with no luck. I am using jQuery 1.9.1

Here is my function's code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.createGallery = function(options) {
        var theObject = $(this);
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            server: 'http://localhost/jQuery%20Gallery/images/galleries/',
            galleryName: 'Test',
            galleryWidth: 800,
            galleryImageMargin: 20,
            galleryImageColumns: 2,
            galleryTargetFolder: 'homepage_gallery',
            imageQuality: 100
        }, options);

        var galleryImageWidth = settings.galleryWidth / settings.galleryImageColumns;
        var imageUrl = settings.server+settings.galleryTargetFolder;

        var otherMargin = Math.round(settings.galleryImageMargin / 2);
        var finalImageWidth = Math.round(galleryImageWidth - settings.galleryImageMargin);
        var finalImageHeight = Math.round(galleryImageWidth / 1.4);
        var finalGalleryWidth = settings.galleryWidth - settings.galleryImageMargin;

        $(this).before('<style>'+$(this).selector+' li:nth-child('+settings.galleryImageColumns+'n+1) { margin-left: 0; } '+$(this).selector+' li:first-child { margin-left: 0; } '+$(this).selector+' { width: '+finalGalleryWidth+'px; margin: 0px; } '+$(this).selector+' li { display: inline-block; list-style: none; margin-left: '+settings.galleryImageMargin+'px; margin-bottom: '+otherMargin+'px; } </style>');

        $.ajax({
            url: imageUrl,
            success: function(data){
                var extension = '.jpg';
                $(data).find("a:contains("+extension+")").each(function(){
                    // will loop through 
                    var filename = $(this).attr("href");
                    $('<li></li>').html('<a href="'+imageUrl+'/'+filename+'" class="fancybox"><img src="thumbnail.php?src='+imageUrl+'/'+filename+'&q='+settings.imageQuality+'&h='+finalImageHeight+'&w='+finalImageWidth+'"/></a>').appendTo(theObject);
                });
            }
        });

    };
}(jQuery));
```

Which is called like this, and works perfectly:
HTML: `<ul id="images"></ul>`

jQuery:

```
$('#images').createGallery({
    server: 'http://localhost/jQuery%20Gallery/images/galleries/',
    galleryName: 'Test',
    galleryWidth: 800,
    galleryImageMargin: 20,
    galleryImageColumns: 2,
    galleryTargetFolder: 'homepage_gallery',
    imageQuality: 100
});
```

Now, what i want to do is add a class to the new elements so that i can target them in ie8 to add a class to it. I have tried this:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    $(e.target).addClass('triggerMargin');
});
```

Which i have placed in the bottom of the function and it works fine in firefox and chrome etc, yet it is totally ignored in ie8. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of jQuery is implemented? jQuery 2.x dropped support for IE < 9.

Comment: DOMNodeInserted is not supported in IE8. Why would you want to use this kind of event anyway?

Comment: I need to target the nth-child(2n+1) to add a class to it for a fix in ie8. I was doing this to test it out

Comment: What do you need to fix? Something relative to CSS?

Comment: try use this: $('#target div:nth-child(2)').addClass('triggerMargin');

Comment: @A.Wolff I may re word my question as i believe i may have missed my point. I have li's dynamically being added to the ul#images, i have css that targets the nth-child(2n+1) which works fine for newer browsers, i wanted to target the same in ie8 and add a class to fix the issue. But it won't add the class to the elements as they technically dont exist until the function runs

Comment: I've fixed it. Thanks for looking though guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by doing the following
`theObject.children('li:nth-child(2n+1)').addClass('triggerMargin');`

where `theObject` is equal to `$(this)` for the object being targeted to add a class to it's children

Comment: Thx for posting your fix. And ya, jquery handles support for `:nth-child` ;)